# Rails Model Method Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I've got the following code in my model:

```
attr_accessor :display_time_reader
attr_reader :display_time_reader
```

with the following display_time_reader= method:

```
def display_time_reader=(days_before_start)
   self.date_to_show_ad=self.start_time-days_before_start.to_i.days
end
```

I'm submitting to it with the following params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wb7acGREdNH2aeuYjye51wwaWdMXgTYvAcNxoDR9HAE=", "sale"=>{"start_time(3i)"=>"13", "start_time(2i)"=>"1", "start_time(1i)"=>"2012", "start_time(4i)"=>"23", "start_time(5i)"=>"00", "end_time(3i)"=>"14", "end_time(2i)"=>"1", "end_time(1i)"=>"2012", "end_time(4i)"=>"01", "end_time(5i)"=>"00", "display_time_reader"=>"7"}, "commit"=>"create"}
```

However I'm  getting the following error being returned:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have
>   expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating
>   nil.-

Controller code:

```
def new
  user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @sale = user.sales.build
  @locations = user.locations
  1.times { @sale.items.build; @sale.build_location }
end

def create
 @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
 @sale.user_id = current_user.id

 logger.debug "Sale object!!!  #{@sale.inspect}"
 respond_to do |format|
   if @sale.save
     format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render json: @sale, status: :created, location: @sale }
   else
     format.html { render action: "new" }
     format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: You submit to an action, not a model. What's nil?

Comment: @DaveNewton - the code presented above is in a model. It doesn't specify what is nil.

Comment: I understand it's in a model, but we don't really know when the nil occurs, under what circumstances, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton it flags this error when I'm trying to create a new record

Comment: app/models/sale.rb:20:in `display_time_reader='
app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:56:in `new'
app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:56:in `create'

Comment: Assuming that the one line of code you show is the one where the error occurs, then it's `self.start_time` that's nil (because that's what you're subtracting from, and the error is that nil doesn't have a '-' method). You should figure out where the model's start_time gets set, and why it isn't.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus - if I'm trying to access the property "start_time" from the form of which has just been submitted via the view, before it gets saved to the database, using self.start_time is the correct way? It's being defined by the view using `<%= f.datetime_select :start_time, :minute_step => 10, :default => Time.now, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>`

Comment: I dunno, I'd include the action code, I guess.

Comment: `def new
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @sale = user.sales.build
    @locations = user.locations
    1.times { @sale.items.build; @sale.build_location }
  `end

Comment: `def create
    @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
    @sale.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: "Sale was successfully created." }
        format.json { render json: @sale, status: :created, location: @sale }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: Please edit your question to include this new code; don't put it in comments

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - sorry, have updated the question

Comment: What *is* start_time? The params for it have parens/args.

Comment: @DaveNewton start time is a datetime property of the Sale model (used as the start time/date of an event).

Comment: Can you guarantee its value is set by the AR initializer's hash entry before the subtracted value's setter is called? I dunno, I might use an after_initialize callback instead.

Comment: @DaveNewton looks like you are correct. I've solved this by using the before_save callback as this guarantees every time the record is adjusted the correct time will be used :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, yeah, before_save makes more sense--good catch. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `self.start_time` might be `nil` (hence calling method `-` is undefined). Can you guarantee that `self.start_time` is not `nil`?

Comment: but the params suggest that is shouldn't be nil no??

Comment: No, `self.start_time` is the only thing (in anything you have shown so far) that has the subtract method called on it. If `self.start_time` is nil, then it won't have a `-` method. Make sure `self.start_time` is initialized, either on construction or in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the initialiser's hash entry wasn't set before the values was trying to be subtracted, so therefore a nil error was occurring. Fixed this by using the `before_save` callback as this guarantees every time the record is saved the correct start_time will be calculated.